# Calculate or get file integrity

Tags: javascript, subresource-integrity

There is any way to get or calculate the file integrity hash?

e.g:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

For the script above the browser calculate the file sha256 and comparing it to the given attribute integrity `o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=`.

So my question is if I can get the browser calculation for the real file (the one that the client received) via web api or something like that?

I read about `Request.integrity` at [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/integrity](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) but wen i try to use it i get an empty string.

```
const myRequest = new Request('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js');
const myIntegrity = myRequest.integrity;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a site for Subresource Integrity (SRI) hashtag generation - https://www.srihash.org/

Or it can be generated manually with `openssl`. Like `openssl dgst -sha512 -binary myfile.js | openssl base64 -A`. Then add a constant `sha512-` before the hash to get the proper value for the `integrity` attribute.